# How to make a few open menu ID in module Menu Accordeon CK?

Tags: joomla, module

In module "Menu Accordeon CK" there is a field "Item ID opened by default", where
ID, you can specify that you want to make the menu open by default. So I need to specify more than one such ID. For example:
108, 129, 30, 165
But realistically, can run only one ID. How do it more?

This code which specifies the ID of the menu items

```
. "defaultopenedid : '" . $params->get('defaultopenedid') . "',"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify one Itemid because these IDs represent Menu Items and the settings and security for them.  In other words, there's isn't any practical way to open more than one menut item (Itemid).  I think you may need to revisit what you're trying to accomplish because it seems highly unlikely that you want to open more than one menu item.

It would appear that Menu Accordion CK is giving you the ability to open some page, but use a particular Menu Itemid so that you'll get the modules and template settings that you've specified for the Menu Item to be used.